# wxPython-4.0.3 -- Prevent overlapping expanding panels

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I am trying to build a wx.Panel object that has multiple paragraphs of individually wrapped text. When the parent panel becomes too small the paragraphs overlap and hide portions of the text.

How do I create a panel with flowing text that does not get hidden by other objects when the frame is resized? I want each paragraph to flow nicely when the window is resized; however, I do not want paragraphs to collide with each other when the window becomes too small.

The Panel.SetMinSize doesn't seem to be a candidate as I will never know the minimum height of a flowing paragraph based on the width of the window.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        frame_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        text1 = wx.StaticText(self, label=self.big_string_one())
        text2 = wx.StaticText(self, label=self.big_string_two())
        color_panel = wx.Panel(self)
        color_panel.SetMinSize(size=wx.Size(-1, 10))
        color_panel.SetMaxSize(size=wx.Size(-1, 10))
        color_panel.BackgroundColour = "blue"
        frame_sizer.Add(text1, 1, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        frame_sizer.Add(color_panel, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        frame_sizer.Add(text2, 1, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        self.SetSizer(frame_sizer)

    def big_string_one(self):
        retval =  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " \
                  "Ut ipsum lectus, mollis et pellentesque at, dapibus " \
                  "eu, laoreet dui. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora " \
                  "torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. " \
                  "Curabitur vestibulum, turpis fringilla convallis " \
                  "commodo, lectus lorem pharetra metus, non interdum magna " \
                  "convallis. Sed id metus in leo porttitor eleifend. " \
                  "Vivamus eget arcu at ligula ullamcorper consequat eget " \
                  "non turpis. Duis consequat ultrices dolor eu porta. Cras " \
                  "malesuada elementum urna, sed vulputate metus."
        return retval

    def big_string_two(self):
        retval =  "Morbi finibus hendrerit lacinia. Vestibulum eget metus " \
                  "vitae mi vehicula dignissim. Donec lobortis dignissim " \
                  "nisl, rutrum viverra nisl vulputate sed. Quisque quis " \
                  "placerat. Ut tincidunt dolor justo, fermentum lacinia " \
                  "metus bibendum a. Morbi ornare id ligula a eleifend. " \
                  "Phasellus at ultricies ante. Praesent malesuada nunc " \
                  "tortor, vel accumsan ex tempus at. Praesent eget ligula " \
                  "ac purus pharetra semper rutrum a nunc. Donec et " \
                  "lobortis mauris, non suscipit erat. Cras sagittis urna " \
                  "lobortis tortor vestibulum, vel pulvinar nisi finibus."
        return retval


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    my_frame = MyFrame(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The window is sized and both paragraph texts flows nicely
[image]

The window is now smaller and text of the first paragraph is cropped by the blue spacer.
[image]

My preference is to have the text for all paragraphs flow nicely but not have them overlap each other when the window becomes smaller.

Comment: `When the parent panel becomes too small the paragraphs overlap and hide portions of the text` - What do you think should happen if there is insufficient space?

Comment: I want the text to flow when the window is resized;however I do not want the objects to overlap each other. Obviously the window is allowed to clip the viewable content. I don’t want internal objects to overlap. If I set a minimum size this can be achieved; however with flowing text the minimum height for the text area changes depending on the width of the window.

Comment: Use a ScrolledPanel instead. Then nothing will overlap.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That is what I ended up doing.